# Is there a way to remove dev days from Story Points?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

In the cards under Planning there is a Story Points section.  It also has "(dev days)" next to it.  There is a concern that this might cause confusion so I was wondering if there is a way to edit it and remove the (dev days) part.

Story Points (dev days):

[image: Story Points (dev days)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can use `witadmin exportwitd` to download the workitem definition, change the field/form and the push the work item type definition back in using `witadmin importwitd`.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/design-work-item-form?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts